# VB.Net DGV - Suspend Filters in a BindingSource

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview

My question it's simple. Exists some method to suspend the auto-filtering in a DGV using BindingSource.Filter?

Example:

1) Creates custom filter:

```
DGVlink.DataSource.Filter = "Column1 = 'A'"
```

2) The user modifies manually the Column1 of a row.

In the normal scenario, the row modified by the user will filter automatically (Because the value of the column1 is different to 'A').

I want to avoid that. Exists a manner to suspend or freeze the filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Temp dataset to copy the initial filtered dgView and set the datasource of dgview to the temp dataset.
This will stop binding source filter. After user make changes, write the changes to original dataset and save it with adapter.update method

Or

Use the dataview to create a filtered original datatable and set that as datasource of dgview

Comment: This method should consume a lot of memory.